# QlikView webpart for SharePoint not displaying objects in property pane

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, qlikview

I've been working with SharePoint for a few years now but am quite new to QlikView. I'm trying to get the QlikView web parts working in WSS 3.0.

The issue I'm currently facing is getting the Objects drop down populated in the web part properties pane. I am able to retrieve the list of documents (and when I select a document, I can see the browser retrieving something from the server) but the "Type" and "Object" drop downs remain empty apart from the default options ("<all>" and "<select object>" respectively).

A bit about the environment:

- We are running QlikView 10.0.8715.5 (64bit) and Windows SharePoint Services (WSS) 3.0.
- SharePoint and QlikView are running on two separate servers.
- We use Kerberos authentication (this seems to be set up correctly since I’m able to retrieve the initial list of documents).
- The QlikView server is running Win 2008 R2 Ent with SP1
- I can successfully browse documents using the QlikView web site hosted on the QlikView server and then open them in the Ajax client.
- I have been told that the QlikView license should work with web parts.
- The QlikView Ajax site is hosted in IIS on the QlikView server.

Am I misunderstanding something here? For example, are there certain types of documents that cannot be opened in the web part client? Should I be able to view objects from, for example, the “What’s New in Qv10” document?

Can anyone give me some ideas of possible causes? I’ve trawled the logs on the QlikView server and could not find any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that our QlikView Test server license did not include web parts. Unfortunately this is not communicated back to the client or even logged to the QV server logs.

Answer (score 0):

The QlikView web parts for SharePoint are chargable on the QV side. See http://www.qlikview.com/us/explore/pricing. Note that it will work with free versions of SP, i.e. WSS 3.0 or SharePoint 2010 Foundation. JK